# Trouble with Pear in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I'm trying to install [PhpDocumentor 2](http://www.phpdoc.org/), and after following the steps for the installation through PEAR, I get the following message:

> PEAR_Config::writeConfigFile fopen('C:\Windows\pear.ini','w') failed
>   (fopen(C:\Windows\pear.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied)

So I checked the pear configuarion: `$ pear config-show` and see that things are all over the place. Any idea on how to correct this?

Also, the pear.ini file is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix the `pear.ini-in-c:\windows` problem unfortunately.

A solution is to run the terminal as administrator, and run the pear install command in it.

If you want to modify the locations, use `pear config-set key value`.